# Classica asp: Checkbox and unhide dropdown control

Tags: asp-classic

I need to know how to handle the following scenario in Classical ASP. Please assist me with some sample as I am new to classical ASP

By default a dropdown control should be hidden

If Checkbox.value = Yes Then
   Show the dropdown control with values
Else
   Hide the dropdown control
End if

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple - if your checkbox has the name attribute `mycheckbox` then you could use something like this

```
<% If Request.Form("mycheckbox") = "Yes" then %>
<select name="mydropdown">
<option value="1">Value 1</option>
<option value="2">Value 2</option>
<option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<% End If %>
```

What you need to understand is that Classic ASP is server side - which means that the code is executed on the server rather than the browser.  This means that in order to get your select dropdown to appear you'll need to post a form to the server and reload the page.  If you want your dropdown to appear as soon as the checkbox is clicked then you should be looking for a client side solution with CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks John, I will try this and get back for any further help.